# Transpose of a set - Orthogonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E\subset \Bbb R^3$ be a plane $\{(x,y,z)^T\in \Bbb R^3: x+y+z=0 \}$. Find a orthonormal basis for E and expand it to a orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$. Calculate the $proj_Ew$ for a vector $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)^T\in \Bbb R^3$

So for the first part of the problem:

Let $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ be the basis for the plane. We apply Gram-Schmidt.

I can check the results with calculators online, so I won't bore you with that.

We have $b_1=\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}$
$b_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3/2}}\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}$

Now we take a linearly independent vector relative to the two vectors we used for the plane and apply Gram-Schmidt again. Since this part is not something i want to ask so i will skip the calculations.

So my question is, what is the transpose of a set? What does it do here? My TA said my work is correct, but I just did it the same way i would if E didn't have the transpose sign up there.

Comment: Are you talking about the $(x,y,z)^T$? Nothing special going on, it's just that we usually denote vectors as columns by convention, but that gets awkward to write out in a line, so sometimes we just write a vector as a row to save space, and then put a transpose sign to signal that it's like a column vector

Comment: Ehm i think im a bit confused with something , ill try to figure out myself first

Comment: $b_2$ is just the normalized version of $b_1$. I think you copied the wrong other vector from your orthogonalization. The other basis vector should have been $$b_1 = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$. There are no sets being transposed here, just individual vectors. If you did have some set of matrices $M$, then $M^T$ would generally be $M^T := \{ m^T\mid m \in M\}$.